# Is there a way to call "s3.Object()" from boto3 python lambda function twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to use the following two times in the same function but get the invalid syntax error in aws lambda function.
i am trying to make these two different files in the same s3 bucket. please help

> this works fine

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name = <region-name>, aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
s3.Object(<bucket_name>, 'filename.txt').put(Body = "somedata")
```

> But when i use this  it give invalid syntax error

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name = <region-name>, aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
s3.Object(<bucket_name>, 'filename.txt').put(Body = "somedata")
s3.Object(<bucket_name>, 'differentfilename.txt').put(Body = "some else data")
```

i am trying to make these two different files in the **same s3 bucket**. please help

Comment: This code works just fine in a Python 3.7 Lambda function. Please check what you have posted matches what you're using and post back the full, and exact, error message and indicate which line of code it's happening on.

Comment: **Side-note:** You should not be referencing Access Key / Secret Key in an AWS Lambda function. Simply assign the function an IAM Role and boto3 will automatically obtain the credentials. So, just use: `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`

Comment: Thank you so much :) @JohnRotenstein can you tell me how can i use credentials in javascript lambda function while retiving the files stored on my s3 bucket?

Comment: Lilly, simply make the desired API calls. No need to worry about credentials. The Javascript SDK will automatically obtain credentials from the IAM Role that is assigned to the Lambda function. Just make sure that IAM Role has the permissions required by the Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add

```
time.sleep(0.1)
```

sleeper in between the functions.

*just a work around*